# Does anyone have documentation for a CoroWare Explorer?

Tags: mobile-robot, ros

I have inherited a CoroWare Explorer from someone who used it for their PhD research years ago. They have no documentation on the robot, and I cannot find any online. Does anyone have a user's manual or any other documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic specifications of the CoroWare Explorer are available on the [Robosavvy website](https://robosavvy.com/store/coroware-explorer.html) (although they no longer carry the product):

**Explorer Specifications**

- Dimensions: 23”L x 21”W x 16”H
- CPU: 2.0 GHz
- RAM: 1 GB
- Disk Space / ROM: 80 GB
- Wi-Fi: 802.11 b/g/n
- GPS: Yes
- Voltage Sensor: Yes
- Maximum Speed: 2 feet per second
- Base Payload Capacity: 15 lbs
- Base Type: Articulated 4 wheel drive
- Steering: Skid
- Obstacle Handling: Can clear 6" obstacles
- Camera: High quality 2 MegaPixel color camera
- Digital Inputs: 8
- Digital Outputs: 8
- Analog Inputs: 7
- Optional Pan/Tilt Camera: Yes
- Battery: 13 AH
- Battery Life: 2.5 - 4 hours
- Windows: XP, Supporting C-language API
- Linux: Ubuntu, Supporting Player
- Player / Stage: Yes
- Sample Software: Yes

---

The [manual for the basic Corobot](https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/PDF/corobot-user-guide.pdf) is available in pdf form from the Robotshop website.

Since the CoroWare Explorer was apparently built to:

> "... expand on the capabilities of the CoroBot and deliver a rugged indoor/outdoor robot that can withstand environmental elements such as dirt, dust, leaf debris, sand, gravel and shallow puddles."

This may help get you started. The Explorer has 'extra ports and surface mounting space', but the pages I found don't say much about other differences.

---

The  [CoroWare website](https://www.coroware.com/) is unhelpful, to put it mildly.  It states that it is "under construction" with a copyright date of 2023!

However, [Satarchy Robotics](http://www.satarchysoftware.com/products/robosatarchy.php) were apparently in partnership with CoroWare, and offer a contact option on their webpage.  They may be able to help with more documentation.